# box-sizing: border-box для кнопки :active

Tags: css3, вёрстка

Не работает css3 свойство `box-sizing: border-box` для кнопки при нажатии (т.е. псевдосостояние - `:active`)...

**Одидается поведение**: при нажатии, над кнопкой должна появиться линия `border: 3px solid red;` но кнопка не должна увеличиться в размерах... Т.е. появиться внутренняя линия красного цвета, НЕ увеличивая размер кнопки на 3px...
**Вместо этого!** Когда появляется линия над кнопкой, вся кнопка увеличивается в размере на 3px...

**Пробовал:**
 1. Гуглить - нет информации, почему с-во не работает на кнопку (всё остальное пашет - блоки, секции, и даже ссылки с `display: block`)!
 2. Ставить доп. свойства типо: `-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;`

**Вот код!**

```
.button{
    transition-property: background-color, color, border;
    transition-duration: 150ms, 100ms, 50ms;

    font: inherit;

    cursor: pointer;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.button-red:active{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.700);
    background-color: #d7373b;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 3px solid #c13135;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `box-sizing: border-box`, даёт понять элементу, что `border` и `padding` будет идти внутрь элемента, уменьшая его размер.

У вас размера нет, следовательно ему нужно удержать содержимое + добавить `border`

```css
.button{
    transition-property: background-color, color, border;
    transition-duration: 150ms, 100ms, 50ms;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.button:active{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.700);
    background-color: #d7373b;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 3px solid #c13135;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Если мы зададим статичный размер, то сразу получится то, что вы хотите.

```css
.button{
    transition-property: background-color, color, border;
    transition-duration: 150ms, 100ms, 50ms;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 30px;
}

.button:active{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.700);
    background-color: #d7373b;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 3px solid #c13135;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Но, при этом двигается содержимое и это логично.

---

Есть другой вариант.
Для достижения нужного эффекта, использовать не `border`, а [`box-shadow`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow)

```css
.button{
    transition-property: background-color, color, box-shadow;
    transition-duration: 150ms, 100ms, 50ms;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #c13135 inset;
}

.button:active{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.700);
    background-color: #d7373b;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #c13135 inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Нажми на меня</div>
```

Comment: @Виктор К. Вы спросили, вам ответили. Должна же быть какая-то обратная связь. Если ответ вам был полезен, то отметьте его как решение.